# Rapahel js : dynamic positioning and animations

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm new to js and web dev in general, and i want to add animations to my website using raphael js.

Here  is the code I use for a basic slide-in animation:

```
paper.text('1000','25%','this is a\ntest').animate({x: '50'}, 1000, 'linear');
```

([test it here](http://raphaeljs.com/playground.html))

It works fine when i put fixed values for the x parameter. However, when i use dynamic positioning, the animation doesn't occur, and the text waits for the duration of the animation before positioning itself. At least the final positioning is what i'm looking for:

```
paper.text('300%','25%','this is a\ntest').animate({x: '50%'}, 1000, 'linear');
```

Why isn't it working ?
Is there a way around ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure raph can work like that (animating to a percentage), I may be wrong though.

Is this the sort of thing you are after ?

```
paper.text( paper.width * 3,'25%','this is a\ntest').animate({x: paper.width / 2}, 1000, 'linear');
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, I just had to resize the paper using the container width and height to make it work.

However, it does not scale when you resize the windows, whereas the other positioning method did. I guess i'll have to do without this feature ...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are after dynamically vs manually, but I would imagine what you want is still possible. There are ways for example to get the width of a div like document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth. There is a fiddle here using jquery that illustrates detecting window resizes that could be tied in. http://jsfiddle.net/UqYCr/